# How to check Scrollable interface is empty?

Tags: hql, scrollableresults

Returning from a `hql` query, how to check if a `ScrollableResults` object is empty?

`scrollable.first`?

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollableResults` object has a method `first()`

first() returns boolean value.

`TRUE` if exists the first element, `FALSE` otherwise

A possible check you can implement is:

```
ScrollableResults myScrollable ...

if (myScrollable != null && myScrollable.first()) {
    // add your business logic
}
```

You can see [**here**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/ScrollableResults.html#first())